# AVR USART doesn't work as expected

Tags: gps, avr, uart, atmega

I'm using an ATMega32 with a GPS module to display some data on a LCD display (longitude and latitude). 
The GPS module sends a string of data every second at 9600 bps.
The string is a NMEA sentence, starting with a $ sign and I use that character to synchronize the receiver (AVR UART).

this is the code I use:

```
// GPS.h

void GPS_read(char *sentence)           
{
  while ((*sentence = USART_receive()) != '$')
    ;
  USART_receive_string(++sentence);
}



// USART.h

unsigned char USART_receive(void)
{
  while (!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)))
    ;
  return UDR;
}

void USART_receive_string(char *string)
{
  do
  {
    *string = USART_receive();
  } while (*string++ != '\n');                             // NMEA sentences are <CR><LF> terminated
  *string = '\0';   
}
```

I pass a char array to GPS_read and then display the string on the LCD.
depending on the timing I choose for displaying the data, I get some rubbish data consisting of a $G and a \n character.

I'm making some mistake here, but it's been two days and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong (I'm a novice embedded programmer :) )

please help!
thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your baudrate of TX and RX is correct ? Check for frame errors as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few errors with your code, try this:

You haven't included your char array declaration, but I would advise you use an indexer to keep track of which element you are reading and/ or writing to within your array.

```
unsigned char Sentence[*Insert array size here*];
unsigned char Indexer = 0;
```

and as for your functions, I'd say your USART_receive() function is fine, but try...

```
void GPS_read(char *sentence)
{
    unsigned char Data = USART_receive();   // Read initial value
    while (Data != '$')                     // while Data is not a '$' ...
        Data = USART_receive();             // ... Read the USART again until it is

    sentence[Indexer++] = Data;
    USART_receive_string(sentence);        
}

void USART_receive_string(char *string)
{
    unsigned char Data = USART_receive();

    while (Data != '\n')
    {
        *string[Indexer++] = Data;
        Data = USART_receive();
    }
    *string[Indexer] = '\n';
}
```

Comment: `*sentence[Indexer++]`? - I don't think so.

Comment: "There are a few errors with your code" - What are those errors?

Comment: Why? *sentence points to the address of the char array, Index is being used as an indexer, once the value of Data is stored to that particular element of the array, increment Indexer by one to 'point' to the next element in the array ready for the USART_receive_string() function. What am I missing?

Comment: Nope, `sentence` *points* to something, `*sentence` is a `char`.

Comment: Ah, couldn't see what was staring me in the face - I've edited the answer.

Comment: `*string[Indexer++] = Data`... :o)

Comment: Still, I haven't found an error in the OP's code. What did you find?

Comment: Well judging by the fact that you didn't already spot it I'm guessing my understanding is wrong, but as far as I'm aware, considering that the OP is storing the data into an array of chars, sentence++ and *string++ won't increment the pointers to point to the next element in the array but rather the address after the last element in the array. In truth, even if this isn't the case I wouldn't think its a good idea as you don't keep track of which element you have read or written to.

Comment: I agree that the OP's code might be more clear with a little less pointer arithmetic, like your proposal. Nevertheless, to me it looks as if the code should actually work. That's why I assume the error is in another part of the program that wasn't disclosed to us yet.